# Intel Pin Tool : Not recognizing user defined functions with icc

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, icc, intel-pin

I have successfully built and using [Intel Pin Tool 3.7](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-binary-instrumentation-tool-downloads). I am using the `insmix.so` tool of the `Insmix` directory for finding the instruction mix of a user defined function (function name is "myfunc").

What I observe is:
when I compile my test program using gcc (with no `-O2` or `-O3` options), the tool writes the insmix count of "myfunc" to the tracefile insmix.out. When gcc is used with `-O2` or `-O3` options nothing about "myfunc" is printed in the tracefile.

Also with the icc compiler no trace is printed about "myfunc".
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler probably doesn't preserve the symbol for your function. Compile your program with the `-g -debug all` flags.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When icc is used with -O2 and -g, still the symbol information for my function is not preserved. Any idea?

Comment: I added another flag, try this?